# Ron de Bruin RangetoHTML with Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, report, html-email

I'm using the Ron de Bruin "RangetoHTML" function to generate a report daily mail regarding the daily status of some projects to some people.
When I use the excel sheet via a Microsoft machine, everything works fine but, using the same VB Script on a Mac machine, an error occurs. I tried to search over the net a possible solution but it seems not solved yet and for me it's difficult to figure out a solution.

The excel sheet is composed by 2 tabs (PROJ1 and PROJ2) and data are contained in tables identified in the range E5:F18 in tab PROJ1, and in the range B1:E14 in tab PROJ2.
I need also the layout of the data to be converted in html (not just the text content of the cells).

Field E26 contains the subject of the email of the current tab on which the script is called
Field E27 contains email address of the "to" field of the email
Field E28 contains email address(es) of the "cc" field of the email

Here's the code.
I have a first module having the following instructions:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()

Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

' Variable definition (variables to be passed to the RangetoHTML function)

' ****** TO BE MODIFIED IN CASE OF DIFFERENT STRUCTURE OF THE EXCEL ******
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

' ****** ---------------------------------------------------------- ******

' Body text definition
Dim StrBody As String


StrBody = "<html><body>Hi all,<br/>here a daily report for the progress status of all the activities.<br/><br/>Warning: activities in <b>BLOCKED</b> or in <b>WAITING INFORMATIONS</b> status are potentially dangerous for the project.</br></br></br></br></body></html>"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next


' Setting the variables (here the range of data to be exported for each tab is defined

' ****** TO BE MODIFIED IN CASE OF DIFFERENT STRUCTURE OF THE EXCEL ******

Set rng = Sheets("PROJ1").Range("E5:F18").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng2 = Sheets("PROJ2").Range("B1:E14").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' ****** ---------------------------------------------------------- ******

Subj = Range("E26").Value

On Error GoTo cleanup



        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = Range("E27").Value
            .CC = Range("E28").Value
            .Subject = Subj
            ' ****** TO BE MODIFIED IN CASE OF DIFFERENT STRUCTURE OF THE EXCEL ******
            .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & RangetoHTML(rng2)' <--- BUILD OF THE EMAIL'S BODY
            ' ****** ---------------------------------------------------------- ******

            .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

the 2nd module is the Ron de Bruin's RangetoHTML function:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook


TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"


'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With


'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")


'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False


'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile


Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

The error returned is 429: activex component can't create object
and the following part is yellow-highlighted:

```
'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
```

Operating System is MacOS Sierra and excel is 2016 edition.

Does somebody know how to solve it?

Comment: Ron's probably a good place to start! http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mail.htm

Comment: I honestly tried it but apparently it's not solved yet. I went over some other forums but again... nothing!